# Custom UIAlertView with block callback

Tags: ios, block, uialertview, objective-c-blocks

MyAlertView (subclass of UIAlertView) has this method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (self.clickedButtonAtIndexBlock != NULL)
        self.clickedButtonAtIndexBlock(buttonIndex);
}
```

My question is how do I define the callback when I create the alert view? Obviously this is wrong:

```
alert.clickedButtonAtIndexBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"clicked: %d", buttonIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
.h
typedef void (^MyClickedIndexBlock)(NSInteger index);

@interface YouInterface : YourSuperclass
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClickedIndexBlock clickedIndexBlock;
@end

.m
//where you have to call the block
if (self.clickedIndexBlock != nil)
    self.clickedIndexBlock(buttonIndex);

// where you want to receive the callback
alert.clickedIndexBlock = ^(NSInteger index){
    NSLog(@"%d", index);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written a blog post about how to (and why) add block callbacks to alert views, action sheets and animations:

http://blog.innovattic.com/uikitblocks/

If you just want a working implementation of this you can download the sources files from GitHub:

https://github.com/Innovattic/UIKit-Blocks

Usage:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My easy alert"  
                                                message:@"Would you like to perform some kind of action?"
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert setHandler:^(UIAlertView* alert, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    NSLog(@"Perform some kind of action");
} forButtonAtIndex:[alert firstOtherButtonIndex]];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [OpinionzAlertView](https://github.com/Opinionz/OpinionzAlertView) I have used it in few projects, works good for me. Here is sample:

```
OpinionzAlertView *alert = [[OpinionzAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                            message:@"message"
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@[@"Done"]
                                            usingBlockWhenTapButton:^(OpinionzAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {

                                                NSLog(@"buttonIndex: %li", (long)buttonIndex);
                                                NSLog(@"buttonTitle: %@", [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
                                            }];
[alert show];
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

Say you created a class called MyCustomAlert, and you declare it as this variable.

```
MyCustomAlert *myCustomAlert = [[MyCustomAlent alloc] init];
```

You would put this in your header file.

```
- (void)setCompletion:(void (^)(int selectedButtonIndex))completion;
```

And you would put this in your implementation file

```
typedef void (^IntBlock)(int intBlock);
IntBlock _completion;

- (void)setCompletion:(void (^)(int selectedButtonIndex))completion{
    _completion = completion;
}
```

now in the project where you declared "myCustomAlert". If you type in

```
[myCustomAlert setCompletion: // And select the autocomplete item
```

you will end up with this

```
[myCustomAlert setCompletion:<#^(int intBlock)completion#>]
```

the value <#^(int intBlock)completion#> will show up as a bubble like this.

[image]

when you press enter on the value, it will fill in the Block for you to use.

```
[myCustomAlert setCompletion:^(int selectedButtonIndex) {

}
```

when you want to trigger the _completion block in your custom class, you would call it somewhere in your code as follows.

```
- (void) callCompletionWithButtonIndex:(int) index{
    if (_completion != nil) _completion(index);
}
```

hope that clears up the complication.

Comment: In this answer you are not showing which header/implementation file to which you are referring. You also introduce the Custom Alert concept without explaining how it fits into the solution. This forces readers to guess your intent (which is always not good). The answer could be improved by addressing these missed opportunities for clarity.

Comment: The header and implementation file I am referring is yours, not mine. Therefore I cannot provide you with one as this is meant to be placed into your code.. But You are right, I did not provide a _completion call. I have added that.

Comment: When you mention a header and implementation file, how does this tie in? Is it a view controller or is it the subclass of the custom alert? Sorry if my earlier request was unclear. I could simply assume the latter but specificity is always better.

Comment: The header and implementation files are the .h and .m files that are for the class you want to use this function pointer with. You could subclass the UIAlertView, you could create a AlertManager, you could put it on your ViewController, it really depends on what you want to do. The information merely shows how to implement a callback function so that you can create a callback, use it and how to allow the editor to provide you with the block itself :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple class LMSVBlocks to easily display alerts and get block callbacks in 1 line. Hopefully you will find it useful for this purpose

https://github.com/sourabhverma/LMSVBlocks

**Concept:** To make UIAlertView block compatible you need another class (Say LMSVBlockAlert) to handle the delegate method and when UIAlertView delegate will give a callback, LMSVBlockAlert class can send a call back in the block.

**Code:**
(LMSVBlockAlert.m)

Maintain all the instances of LMSVBlockAlert in an array so that they have a strong reference

```
static NSMutableArray *_LMSVblockHandlersArray = nil;
```

Keep the block handler in LMSVBlockAlert

```
@interface LMSVBlockAlert() <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^cancelCompletionBlock)();
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^confirmCompletionBlock)();
@end
```

When a new alert is fired create new instance of LMSVBlockAlert which has a UIAlertView and delegate callbacks

```
+(LMSVBlockAlert*)newInstance{
    LMSVBlockAlert *newIns = [[LMSVBlockAlert alloc] init];
    [LMSVBlockAlert updateHandlerArrayWith:newIns];
    return newIns;
}
```

When alert delegate is fired in LMSVBlockAlert send callback to block and clear this from memory

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0://Cancel
        {
            if(_cancelCompletionBlock){
                _cancelCompletionBlock();
            }
        }
            break;
        case 1://OK
        {
            if(_confirmCompletionBlock){
                _confirmCompletionBlock(alertView);
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [_LMSVblockHandlersArray removeObject:self];
}
```

Now you can have two simple method which can give you UIAlertView callbacks

```
+(UIAlertView*)promptAlertTwoBtn:(NSString*)msg title:(NSString*)title onCancel:(void (^)())onCancel onConfirm:(void (^)())onConfirm{

    return [[LMSVBlockAlert newInstance] showAlertMainWithTitle:title msg:msg onCancel:^{
        onCancel();
    } onConfirm:^(UIAlertView *alertView) {
        onConfirm();
    }];
}

-(UIAlertView*)showAlertMainWithTitle:(NSString*)title msg:(NSString*)msg onCancel:(void (^)())onCancel onConfirm:(void (^)(UIAlertView*))onConfirm{

    UIAlertView *newAlert = nil;


    newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle:title
                    message:msg
                    delegate:self
                    @"Cancel"
                    otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];


    [newAlert show];

    self.cancelCompletionBlock = onCancel;
    self.confirmCompletionBlock = onConfirm;

    return newAlert;
}
```

**Finally**
Hope you found it useful..

Answer (score 0):

You Can simple use these category classes from github.

[Alert_ActionSheetWithBlocks](https://github.com/gurmundi7/Alert_ActionSheetWithBlocks)

This provide Dismiss blocks for both AlertView and action sheets.

For Eg.

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"AlertView+Block" message:@"WithBlocks" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"newAlertViewWithTextFields",@"newAlertViewWithSingleTextField", nil];
[alert showWithFinishBlock:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) 
{ if (buttonIndex == 0) { } else if (buttonIndex == 1) { } }];
```

Apart from this it is also providing methods for text fields..

```
-(void) showWithFinishBlock:(FinishBlock_)block_; //-- AlertView with TextField [simple or secure]

-(void) showWithTextFieldBlock:(TextFieldBlock_)block_ secure:(BOOL)isSecure; //-- AlertView with two textfields username & password
```

You can take a look at example bundled with it.
I hope it will be helpfull to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple extension in Swift, hope it helpful

```
import UIKit

extension UIAlertView {

    func show(completion: (alertView: UIAlertView, buttonIndex: Int) -> Void){
        self.delegate = AlertViewDelegate(completion: completion)
        self.show()
    }

    class func showInput(title: String?, message: String?, cancellable: Bool, completion: (text: String?) -> Void){

        var strOK = NSLocalizedString("OK",comment: "OK")
        var strCancel = NSLocalizedString("Cancel",comment: "Cancel")
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: cancellable ? strCancel : strOK)
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
        if(cancellable) {
            alert.addButtonWithTitle(strOK)
        }
        alert.show { (alertView, buttonIndex) -> Void in
            if(cancellable && alertView.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
                completion(text: nil)
                return
            }
            completion(text: alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text)
        }
    }

    private class AlertViewDelegate : NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {
        var completion :  (alertView: UIAlertView, buttonIndex: Int) -> Void
        var retainedSelf : NSObject?
        init(completion: (UIAlertView, Int) -> Void ) {
            self.completion = completion
            super.init()

            self.retainedSelf = self
        }

        func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
            var retain = self
            retain.retainedSelf = nil
            retain.completion(alertView: alertView, buttonIndex: buttonIndex)
        }
    }
}
```